# Nginx microservice gateway config within kubernetes cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, .net-core

Basically we have a set of microservices we have deployed to a kubernetes cluster hosted in AWS. We would like to run these through a gateway configuration in nginx.

Our current configuration which doesn't work looks something like this-

```
upstream some-api1 {
    server some-api1:80;
}

upstream some-api2 {
    server some-api2:80;
}

upstream some-api3 {
    server some-api3:80;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name gateway.something.com;
    location /api1 {
        proxy_pass  http://some-api1;
    }
    location /api2 {
        proxy_pass  http://some-api2;
    }
    location /api3 {
        proxy_pass  http://some-api3;
    }
}
```

Our services have been built with dotnet core, so the underlying urls would be something like http://some-api1/{api/controllername} . I'm always getting a 404 when I try hitting these endpoints through postman, which tells me it can't resolve these mappings.

However I'm able to access an api within the cluster using an explicit config for an api like so(which is what I don't want to do)-

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name someapi1.something.com;
    location /{
        proxy_pass http://some-api1;
    }   
}..
```

If someone could shed some light on what's wrong with the configuration or recommend the best approach for this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get plain 404 or an nginx default backend 404? How is the nginx exposed to the world outside the cluster (NodePort? LoadBalancer?)? Do you have Kubernetes Service descriptors with the names of the services? If you could include output of 'kubectl get services --all-namespaces' that may help.

Comment: it seems like you need to add the path to the `proxy_pass` as well:   `proxy_pass  http://some-api3/api3;` and if you want to pass the query parameters as well then this would be: `proxy_pass  http://some-api3/api3$is_args$args;`

Comment: I ask in part because I'm wondering whether you'd be better to set up an nginx ingress controller (https://medium.com/kokster/how-to-setup-nginx-ingress-controller-on-aws-clusters-7bd244278509) and use a fanout ingress https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout

Comment: @Ryan - Thanks for the feedback!. I just updated the original post. I double checked the cluster service descriptors everything seems fine there. As a proof of concept I was able to access one api through postman using an explicit configuration as described in my edit. You may be on to something about ingress I need to look into this further. I was hoping it would be a simple configuration thing in nginx that I'm missing.

Comment: @Zakaria - Thanks for your suggestion. I did try what you mentioned this didn't seem to make a difference either. As mentioned in my updated post I was able to access an api with postman using an explicit / mapping.

Comment: If I understood correctly what are you trying to achive, I think you can solve the issue with the rewrite directivei. Try: `location /api1 {rewrite /api1/(.*) /$1  break; proxy_pass  http://some-api1;}`. Same for the other proxy-passes.

Comment: @Luminance I agree. I posted answer before seeing your comment but have updated it to acknowledge that you were first

Answer (score 1):

As @Luminance suggests, you're seeing traffic to /api1 go to some-api1/api1 instead of just some-api1 on the base path for that target service (which is what your app would respond to). Following https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0 you could re-write that target like

```
location /api1 {
       rewrite ^/api1(.*) /$1 break;
       proxy_pass http://some-api1;
    }
```